# Text encoding issue with Powershell

Tags: powershell, encoding

I'm trying to convert a password that's stored in a text file to a SecureString.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
$pwdPath = 'C:\Password.txt'
$pwd = (ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText (Get-Content $pwdPath))
```

When I do this, the password is incorrect and I get an error when I try to use it.  However, if I pass in the contents of the file directly on the command line:

[image]

Then we're good.  At first I thought maybe the file had an extra line break at the end of something.  However, I tried using `.Trim()` and all that stuff.  If I look at the length of the file vs. the length of the string, I get a clue:

[image]

The file is twice the number of bytes as the string.  So, probably some sort of encoding issue.  If I look at the first few bytes:

[image]

I'm not a text encoding expert, but looks like a UTF-16 based encoding (two bytes per character) with no BOM at the beginning (97 is `a`, 52 is `4`, etc).  I tried all sorts of ways to "convert" this file to something compatible with `ConvertTo-SecureString` but so far (Such as `Get-Content $pwdPath | Set-Content -Encoding ASCII ./test.txt`) I haven't found anything that results in a valid password.

Comment: `Get-Content $pwdPath -Encoding Unicode`

Comment: @PetSerAl Works, thanks!!

Comment: How did you create the file?

Comment: @js2010 I didn't.  This is a file Service Fabric creates to share certificates with docker containers.

Comment: This type of file pops up in windows occasionally.  Believe it or not, Notepad can open them, and then save them to unicode with a bom.  Or just `(get-content -encoding unicode file) | set-content -encoding unicode file2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as per @PetSerAl, to access a unicode no bom file, since powershell isn't as clever as notepad:

```
Get-Content $pwdPath -Encoding Unicode
```